# Pagination in category.php not functioning

Tags: php, wp-query, loop, pagination, query-posts

**Original Url: https://www.something.com/category/ftm-atf/**

When I add pagination in, the following url is generated which results in a 404:

**Paginated Url: https://www.something.com/category/ftm-atf/page/2/**

The code is located in **category.php** and looks like the following:

```
<?php
$category = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
query_posts(array( 
'post_type' => 'video',
'showposts' => 6,
'post_status' => 'publish',
'tax_query' => array(
array(
'taxonomy' => 'category',
'field' => 'term_id',
'terms' => array($category->term_id)
)
)
));
?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 

...

<?php endwhile;?>

paginate_links(array('total'=> $wp_query->max_num_pages));
```

I've tried various solutions to no avail, so I feel like something basic is being missed. Essentially, all I need to have happen is to restrict to 6 posts per page, and allow simple pagination.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Never use `query_posts()`: https://www.rarst.net/wordpress/query-posts-breaks-pagination/

Answer (score 1):

if your aim is to restrict the category archive to your post_type 'video' and to 6 posts per page, do not edit category.php, rather use 'pre_get_posts' https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/

example code for your case:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'category_post_type_video_custom' );
function category_post_type_video_custom( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        // Not a query for an admin page.
        // It's the main query for a front end page of your site.
        if ( is_category() ) {
            // It's the main query for a category archive.
            // Let's change the query for category archives.
            $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'video' ) );
            $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 6 );
        }
    }
}
```

virtually directly taken from https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/#targeting-the-right-query

Comment: Thank you Michael. Yes, I keep reading about that and figured it had something to do with this function. I didn't develop the site so I'm jumping in and fixing that the previous person has messed up.

Going with your solution, I'm assuming I add this to functions.php? Also, what should I do with category.php?

Comment: in category.php, remoive everything from before this line `<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>` in your posted code. and consider to add some `if( have_posts() )` code to the fiile.

Comment: Question. Are you saying I should also change `while (have_posts())` to `if( have_posts())` or I should keep them both? Just trying to ensure the loop stays in tact to display the items. Thanks so much! Really excited to solve this issue!

Comment: use both... for a general loop design, see https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/

Comment: Will do. Thanks Michael!

Comment: Hey Michael. I followed the link and fully understand regarding the loop. One final question. In what file should I place the code block you placed above? I know the idea is to get away from editing category.php. I'm thinking functions.php, but wanted to see if you had a different suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: the suggested `add_action( 'pre_get_posts', ...` code belongs into functions.php.

Comment: Excellent! You rock!

Comment: I'm added the code to the end of my functions.php file and I'm getting the following error: "Call to a member function is_main_query() on a non-object"

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: my mistake, I forgot to add a variable in the function; first line should be `function category_post_type_video_custom( $query ) {` - I am correcting this in my answer.

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks! 

One thing I'm not clear about. Is in my initial url, you can see that I'm getting videos from the category "ftm-atf" as shown by: https://www.something.com/category/ftm-atf/

In the code you provided, will the videos still be filtered and paginated by this specific category of videos?